# Heroku. Who can I run the project on php + reactJS?

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, heroku

I need some help running a Laravel / ReactJS app on Heroku.

As I understand, I need to add `vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx` into `Procfile`. I've done that, but how can I run the ReactJS part? I tried the following command:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx public/ && npm run build
```

but in the logs I see:

```
2018-05-28T12:51:03.242771+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=still-sands-40110.herokuapp.com request_id=4b1448e5-76cc-4d4b-94b1-64d67f88b553 fwd="81.25.234.90" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=1439 protocol=https
2018-05-28T12:51:03.478220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/js/app.js" host=still-sands-40110.herokuapp.com request_id=81eafe08-c586-4326-9ff4-432f18522f03 fwd="81.25.234.90" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=707 protocol=https
2018-05-28T12:51:03.479057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/css/app.css" host=still-sands-40110.herokuapp.com request_id=c4c5a94b-a93b-45fb-809f-879f1293531f fwd="81.25.234.90" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=170 protocol=https
/js/app.js - 404
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: If you ask for what the problem implies, `/js/app.js` not found apparently.

Comment: Yes, I see it :)
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was

Procfile:

> web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/ && npm start

package.js:

> "start": "node public/js/app.js"

If you need to use nginx, then to configure the routing you can create your own config
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx_app.conf public/

Comment: bro i have question where is package.js file please be clearer